# Recursive Coin Collecting in a grid

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

How do I write a recursive code that tells me the maximum number of coins I can collect from a grid in which each cell may or may not contain a coin only moving down and right? I also have to use memoization.

```
ex:  [[0,0,1],
      [0,1,1],
      [1,0,0]]
```

max_coins moving only down and right = 2

Comment: There are simpler ways to achieve it, are you sure you want to use recursion?

Comment: Classical Dynamic Programming problem.

Comment: Yes, I am trying several methods

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll need the recurrence relation behind this problem: if the maximum number of coins at cell `[i][j]` is denoted by `C[i][j]`, then

```
C[i][j] = max(C[i - 1][j], C[i][j - 1]) + No. of coins on cell[i][j]
```

If you code using this recurrence, there will be many overlaps of the same calls with the same parameters for different cells, and its complexity would be exponential. To avoid this, you can *store* the results of the intermediate calls in an array and *use* them when they're needed again. This way, you'll need to calculate the value for a cell only once, and the code would be much faster.

So, first create a 2D array that would contain the maximum number of coins you can have at any cell, then populate it with the appropriate values using the recurrence relation. Go from top row to bottom, left to right.

Comment: So this is where I am getting confused. I'm not sure how to store the results in an array.